# Pasar valor de input datetime-local como parámetro en Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tengo un formulario con 2 inputs tipo `datetime-local` y necesito enviarlos a través de Ajax a una función del controlador que hace unas comparaciones y me devuelve un resultado, he intentado de todas las maneras enviar los valores de los inputs, pero aún no tengo resultados...

Este es el script que tengo:

```
function buscar() {
  
            var inicio = $("#hora_ingreso").val();  /* 'Y-m-d H:i:s' */
            var termino = $("#hora_salida").val();
            var data = {
                "_token": $('#token').val(),
                inicio:inicio,
                termino:termino
            };
            $.ajax({
                url:"{{ url('data/consultaTiempo') }}"+`/${inicio}`+`/${termino}`,
                type: "post",
                data: data ,
                success: function (response) {
                    //console.log("todo bien",response);
                    if (response.errores) {
                        console.log('ups');
                    }else {
                        if (response.exito) {

                            console.log(response.exito);
                            /* var dia = response.exito.dia
                            var cliente_id = response.exito.id
                            var nom1 = response.exito.nombre_primario
                            var nom2 = response.exito.nombre_secundario
                            var apePat = response.exito.ape_pat
                            var apeMat = response.exito.ape_mat
                            $('#direccion_particular').val(direccion);
                            $('#nombre_cliente').val(nom1+ nom2 +apePat +apeMat);
                            $('#duracion_procedimiento').val(cliente_id);*/
                        }
                    }
                    //$('#rut').val('');
                }
            });


    }
```

He probado con

1. .val();
2. .value();
3. .date();
4. .datetime();

Y no funciona, solo con `.val()` noté que hace la petición pero los parámetros salen como `undefinded`.

Saludos a todos.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día, intenta lo siguiente :

```
var data = {
            "_token": $('#token').val(),
            inicio:inicio,
            termino:termino
        }; Saca el token de esta variable "data",  y prueba asi:
```

```js
var inicio = $("#hora_ingreso").val();  /* 'Y-m-d H:i:s' */
var termino = $("#hora_salida").val();
var token  =  $("#token").val(),

// Aquí podrías revisar si realmente esta "jalando" el valor de la siguiente manera :  
   alert(inicio);
   alert(termino);
   alert(token);   

 sera muy enfadoso ver las alertas pero es una forma de saber si esta leyendo los valores de tus variables, adicionalmente asegurate que esten escritas igual tu variables que estas solicitando el valor a traves del .val().
```

y en tu data dentro de la petición ajax:

```js
$.ajax({
                url:"tu_archivo_destino",
                type: "post",
                data: {"inicio":inicio, "termino":termino, "token":token},
                success: function (response) {
                    //console.log("todo bien",response);
```

Espero te sirva .
Saludos